# Exporting Org mode file containing LaTeX code to HTML without MathJax

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, html, mathjax

I have recently started using `Org mode` and `Emacs`.
I am trying to export `Org mode` code to HTML and my `Org mode` has `LaTeX` code in it.
To render the `LaTeX` code in the browser, one needs internet connection apparently. E.g.

The default, using `MathJax` with internet: [image: The default, using MathJax, with internet]

The default, using `MathJax`, without internet: [image: The default, using MathJax, without internet]

I **do not** want HTML output where one has to rely on the internet, installation of mathjax packages, etc., just to read a HTML file, for anyone who might have saved this file offline might not be able to read it; requiring such things increases the barrier unnecessarily to just read a file.
I also do not want to rely on options like `#+OPTIONS: tex:dvipng` or `#+OPTIONS: tex:dvisvgm` or any other form of image export.

I would like to work it out of the box in a similar fashion to how it works with `LaTeX` export to PDF.

One can describe the output expected to be similar to what `pandoc` does: `pandoc -o example.html example.tex --standalone --mathml` command exports `LaTeX` to HTML and the output HTML file renders quite well without internet.

Sample `pandoc` output: [image: pandoc export]

But the issue with using `pandoc` on org exported `LaTeX` code is that the HTML export formatting done by `Emacs Org mode` is different from `pandoc`.

This seems to be something very basic, yet I have not found any solution to this despite searching for this online (including `Org mode` documentation) for quite some time.

System Specifications: GNU Emacs 28.0.50 -nw mode in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: According to the `pandoc` man page, only firefox and safari natively support mathml.  What does your sample `pandoc` output look like with another browser?